# Suppose that we exchange elements a[i] and a[i+k], which were originally out of order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

> Prove that at least 1 and at most 2*k - 1 inversions are removed

I don't understand what does it mean by "inversions are removed", and I am not sure where to start.

Comment: You'll have to explain more about the problem if you want any help.

Comment: Make your first line as a blockquote (add ">" at the beginning).

Comment: @JimMischel that's all I have for this question

Comment: *"don't understand what does it mean"*  Who gave 'it' to you?  Why not ask them?

Comment: Not sure what you don't understand so maybe a little example will help. From what I know if you have numbers `a[1], a[2], ... , a[n]` then pair `a[j], a[k]` is inversion when `j < k` and `a[j] > a[k]` for example in `1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 6` inversions are `(5, 4), (7,4) and (7, 6)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list is `1, 3, 2, 4` and it's changed to `1, 2, 3, 4` then you've removed an inversion.

Obviously you've removed at least 1 inversion because `a[i]` and `a[i+k]` were out of order. At most you remove `2*k - 1` because if `a[i]` was bigger than `a[i+1], ... ,a[i+k-1]` then you fix `k-1` inversions. Same for `a[i+k]` being smaller than all below it. Thus the most you can have is `k-1 + k-1 + 1` (the last 1 being the one we counted already) which equals `2k - 1`

Example: `1,10,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2` -> switch `a[2]` with `a[10]`, `k = 8`, 2 is now smaller than 10, and 2 is also smaller than 3-9 which is 7 numbers. Further 10 is now bigger than 3-9 which is, again, 7 numbers, so the improvement is `7 + 7 + 1 = 15 = 2*8 - 1`